# Standby ticket is cancelled on Lufthansa. Is there a compensation?

Tags: delays, compensation, connecting-flights

I'm blocked in Frankfurt due to weather conditions. I missed my connecting flight due to delays. They put me on a waiting list and I waited for 5 hours in the airport.

After there was a 1-hour delay. And finally this flight was cancelled. I'm really not sure that this one was due to weather. If it's not the case, can I get 250 euros compensation?

Comment: You'll need to include your airline.....and where this 250 Euros number comes from? Also have you looked at the related questions?

Comment: 250 euros is due to EU rules for delays, cancellations, etc. My airline is Lufthansa but it is more a question of legislation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sidenote: I was there somewhere in the queues with you, and I know that feeling of frustration.*

The compensation of 250 EUR from EU passenger rights does not apply in the case of delays due to weather conditions, which was clearly the case on that Sunday. Only if the delay on your incoming flight, which caused you to miss your connection, was due to a fault of the airline, I see a chance of compensation.

Comment: Yes, my incoming flight was delayed too, as they said "due to weather in Frankfurt" :)

Comment: Asking this question I was angry and surprised as I saw the plane near the gate and I saw at airport monitors that some flights take off